# Multiple Modal Dialogs with dynamic content from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, modal-dialog

- This is a Mission Control Panel, you have the missions markers on the map and (theoretically) you can open the details of each mission from a button
  inside the popups. All is dynamic, created from json, so there are many markers as the objects inside the json array, many mission details as in json detalis etc.
- I have 2 json file that i use. One for the missions popoup "missioni.json" that is used in a cicle to create markers, popups and the buttons. And other one "infomissione.json" with the details of each mission (in my project i wanna link the two json: the mission with the details with a common key cod-type of mission and code of mission ).
- what i've already goal for know, is to create dynamic popups and  open from it's buttons the modal dialogs.
- what i want is to change dynamically the content of each modal dialog with the corrispondent mission description

NB: here there is the html code, more deep there is the script, all the libraries are loaded from cdn, except images of the markers (you can use others replacing it in the "missioni.json") my style.css(don'think is so important)  and the two json file. i report the two json file down they have to stay in the root. I think it should run.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- link for load Bootstrap css (cdn) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- link for load personalized style, style.css (local) -->  
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <!-- fav icon (local) -->  
    <link rel="icon" href="images/armystar.png"></link>
    <!-- Script for load AngularJS (cdn) -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Script for load WebGL Earth (cdn) -->
    <script src="http://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js"></script>
    <!-- Script for load JQuery (cdn) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Script for load Bootstrap js (cdn) -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Script for load Angular-animate js (cdn) -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <!-- Script for load Bootstrap UI tpls js (cdn) -->
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.js"></script>

    <title>MISSION CONTROL</title>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>       
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->  

<style>
    #buttons {position: absolute; top:10px; left: 10px;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- ANGULAR JS NG-APP -->

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" id="wrap">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="h1-army">mission control</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- CONTENT -->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
            <div ng-controller="customersCtrl as ctrl">
                <div class="col-xs-8"> <div id="earth_div"> </div></div>


                <div id="ModalDCtrl" class="modal fade" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl" id="boxinfo2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3 class="modal-title">MISSION DETAILS</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </script>
                            <!--    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleAnimation()">Toggle Animation ({{ animationsEnabled }})</button> -->
                                <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>

                </div>  <!-- COLLAPSE MODAL CONTROLLER  -->

            </div> <!-- COLLAPSE PRINCIPAL CONTROLLER -->

            <div class="col-xs-2"></div>



        </div>  <!-- COLLAPSE ROW -->
    </div>      <!-- COLLAPSE MAP CONTAINER -->
</div>          <!-- CLOSING AngularJs NG-APP -->
<!-- ------------------------- -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p class="p-secret">{top secret}</p>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SCRIPT FOR WEBGL EARTH MAP AND MODAL WINDOWS INSIDE MAP'S POPUPS
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<script>
    var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log, $http ) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});

    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        vm = this;
        $http.get("missioni.json")
        .success(function (response) {
            vm.missioni = response.missioni; 

            var earth = new WE.map('earth_div');
            WE.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(earth);         var marker = "";
            //alert(vm.names.length);
            function kenzo() {
                alert("I am an alert box!");
}

            angular.forEach(vm.missioni, function(value , key){

                 f(key + ': ' + value.no);

                marker = WE.marker([value.lat, value.long],value.img, 48, 48).addTo(earth);
                marker.bindPopup("<b class='list'> Mission Cod: </b><b class='p-mission'>" + value.codmis + "</b><br>" +
                                 "<b class='list'> Mission Typecode: </b><b class='p-mission'>" + value.codtipo + "</b><br>" +
                                 "<b class='list'> Mission Name: </b><b class='p-mission'>" + value.nome + "</b><br>" +
                                 "<b class='list'> Mission info: </b>" +"<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' onclick=\"openDiag()\">Apri</button>" + "<br>" +
                                 "<b class='list'>Rating: </b><b class='p-mission'>" + value.rate + "</b><br>", 
                                {/*maxWidth: 150,*/ closeButton: true})/*.openPopup()*/ ;
            });

        //var markerCustom = WE.marker([50, -9], '/img/logo-webglearth-white-100.png', 100, 24).addTo(earth);

        earth.setView([38.341806,4.550849], 5);
        earth.setTilt(0);
        earth.setHeading(7);

    });



        $scope.info = function(){
            $scope.showMe = false;
            $http.get("infomissione.json").then(function(response){
            $scope.myData = response.data.infomissione;
            });
        }




    function f(x) {
    //alert(x);
    }



});

 function openDiag() {
    //alert("ok");
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("ModalDCtrl")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.open('lg');
    });
     //angular.element(document.getElementById('ModalDCtrl')).scope().open
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here there are the json files

missioni.json:

```
{
  "missioni":
  [
    {"codmis":"10", "codtipo":"0001", "nome":"black-ops", "lat":"33.568488", "long":"-7.601811", "infobox":"<div ng-controller='ModalDemoCtrl'>  <script type='text/ng-template' id='myModalContent.html'> <div class='modal-header'> <h3 class='modal-title'>I'm a modal!</h3> </div> <div class='modal-body'> <ul> <li ng-repeat='item in items'> <a href='#' ng-click='$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item'>{{ item }}</a> </li> </ul> Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b> </div> <div class='modal-footer'> <button class='btn btn-primary' type='button' ng-click='ok()'>OK</button> <button class='btn btn-warning' type='button' ng-click='cancel()'>Cancel</button> </div> </script>  <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' ng-click='open()'>Open me!</button> <div ng-show='selected'>Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div> </div>", "rate":"3","img":"images/armygrade.png"},
    {"codmis":"11", "codtipo":"0003", "nome":"snake-eater", "lat":"40.851367", "long":"14.267200", "infobox":"<div ng-controller='ModalDemoCtrl'>  <script type='text/ng-template' id='myModalContent.html'> <div class='modal-header'> <h3 class='modal-title'>I'm a modal!</h3> </div> <div class='modal-body'> <ul> <li ng-repeat='item in items'> <a href='#' ng-click='$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item'>{{ item }}</a> </li> </ul> Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b> </div> <div class='modal-footer'> <button class='btn btn-primary' type='button' ng-click='ok()'>OK</button> <button class='btn btn-warning' type='button' ng-click='cancel()'>Cancel</button> </div> </script>  <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' ng-click='open()'>Open me!</button> <div ng-show='selected'>Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div> </div>", "rate":"5","img":"images/armygrade2.png"},
    {"codmis":"12", "codtipo":"0002", "nome":"phantom-pain", "lat":"34.560483", "long":"10.423815", "infobox":"<div ng-controller='ModalDemoCtrl'>  <script type='text/ng-template' id='myModalContent.html'> <div class='modal-header'> <h3 class='modal-title'>I'm a modal!</h3> </div> <div class='modal-body'> <ul> <li ng-repeat='item in items'> <a href='#' ng-click='$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item'>{{ item }}</a> </li> </ul> Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b> </div> <div class='modal-footer'> <button class='btn btn-primary' type='button' ng-click='ok()'>OK</button> <button class='btn btn-warning' type='button' ng-click='cancel()'>Cancel</button> </div> </script>  <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' ng-click='open()'>Open me!</button> <div ng-show='selected'>Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div> </div>", "rate":"5","img":"images/Marker48.png"}
  ]
}
```

and

infomissione.json

```
{
    "infomissione":
    [
        {"codmis":"10", "codtipo":"0001", "nome":"black-ops", "rate":"3","descrizione":"descrizione della missione black-ops"},
        {"codmis":"11", "codtipo":"0003", "nome":"snake-eater", "rate":"5","descrizione":"descrizione della missione snake-eater"},
        {"codmis":"12", "codtipo":"0002", "nome":"phantom-pain","rate":"5","descrizione":"descrizione della missione phantom-pain"}
    ]
}
```

My Mission Control Panel:

[image]

Comment: thanks for format it better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the text you want exhibit to the modal controller

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        },
        text: function() {
            return text[i]; // this being the chosen modal text
        }

      }
    });
```

And in the modal controller you can inject into the scope and use it normally.

Comment: If you need more detail just say

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have some doubts , if i make a cicle with the descriptions array i will have the last [i] description in all my modal dialogs,i want instead , different description in each modal dialog for each marker. another problems probably will be to put exact the right description in the right popup.